# Difference between /etc/init and /etc/inittab in linux file system

Tags: linux

I am a newbie to Linux. I am going through the file system in Linux. Though there are many links in Google stating the difference between /etc/init and /etc/inittab, I am really confused between both. Can anyone give me a clear explanation exactly what is the difference between these both.

Comment: Not much distro uses `/etc/init` unless it's actually a synonym to `/etc/linuxrc`. What distro are you using?

Answer (score 1):

`Inittab` is a file that controls everything that happens when a system is rebooted. (http://www.itworld.com/operating-systems/103722/unix-how-to-linux-etcinittab-file)

`Init` is the first process that boots when booting or rebooting the system and is the parent of every other process, direct or indirect. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init)

Comment: Good catch. Let's hope he's actually referring to the `init` process and not `/etc/init`.

Comment: The first process init is >/sbin/init and not >/etc/init, /etc/init is upstart mechanism in which all other process are spawned based on the signals